What is the definition of a conformal symmetry?
I have been very confused by this after some recent reading. So as far as I know, a conformal transformation (according to the definition in di Francesco et. al.'s book on CFT) is an active coordinate change $x \to x'(x)$ whose effect is to change the metric by a Weyl rescaling
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}(x)\to g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = \Omega(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x)\,.
\end{equation}
So that would mean that a theory that is invariant under the above diffeomorphism is a conformal field theory. However, an alternate definition is invariance under Weyl rescalings which have nothing to do with coordinates but are just local rescalings of the metric
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}(x)\to \Omega(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x)\,.
\end{equation}
On the other hand, my professor also told me that the true symmetry is diffeomorphism invariance and the Weyl rescaling so that we get back the old metric.
My question is: doesn't changing the metric change the theory? I am very confused about the proper definition of conformal symmetry/invariance, and it would be great if someone could clarify it for me. I have looked at the answer here but I'm unsure if I understand how one can change the metric by rescaling and still have the same theory.

Related (disclaimer - these are my answers): https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/635336/8821 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/613017/8821

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449838/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449882/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/612945/2451 , and links therein.

@Prahar thanks but why does di Francesco only talk about the diffeomorphism and not the Weyl rescaling when he talks about conformal invariance?

I'm not sure. Francesco (and many other similar textbooks) are a bit misleading in this regard.
